# How to set a condition in the controller class of spring mvc and display an alert based on that condition in an ajax succes function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

have an application which uses spring MVC. I have a method in the controller class which checks for a condition and set a variable value accordingly.

```
if(!dataMap.isEmpty())
{
  flag =0;
}
else
{
  flag = 1;
}
```

I am calling this method as an ajax call. Now I am trying to check the value of this flag from inside the success function of my ajax, and display alerts accordingly.

```
success:function(data){
    if(flag == 0)
    {
    $("#myAlert").show();
    }
    else
    {
      $("#myAlert1").show();
     }
    },
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: _This doesn't seem to be working_ is not terribly descriptive. Are you getting any errors in the console? Different behavior? Help us help you.

Comment: When I execute the above code, I get the following error in console   :        ' Uncaught ReferenceError: fl is not defined